# Python: How can I extract the numbers nex to the brackets?

Tags: python, merge, extract, data-cleaning

I have some data manually digited but kind of disorganized, in the way sometimes its easy to get the numbers from the brackets but its hareded when they are alones. 
This is for TONS of rows so it maybe has other types of entries

I have tried to just separate numbers or use the extract function but whitout succes.

```
ext = ext['ITEMS'].str.extractall(pat = '(/d{2})')
```

[image: Description]

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you want to extract the numbers inside parentheses `()`?

Comment: Please add formatted text not a picture. Add something people can work with.

Comment: question is not clear to me, can you put like what are the possible conditions and what are your expected results

Comment: Please provide a minimum runnable snippet + expected output. And provide the part about numbers in side parentheses, do you need it and add numbers to column `Q`?

Comment: First, you should escape parenthesis in regex pattern, by adding a `\ ` in front of them : `\(` and `\)`. Second, '/d{2}' seems to mean "two digits" : but the slash is wrong, should be a backslash (`\d{2}`), and in your case you seem to have only one digit, so just `\d` should be better. `\d{1,2}` if you want one or two digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are reading the above type of content from a file named `words.txt` and want to write the desired output to the file named `words2.txt`. You can use the following code to achieve the task, if I understand your requirement correctly from your shared screenshot.

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as reader, open("words2.txt", "w") as writer:
    index_dict = dict()      # stores the indices as keys and list of ITEMs as value
    obj1 = re.compile(r'^\s*(\d+)\s+(.*)')    # this pattern will match the lines starting with an integer(to ignore the header)
    obj2 = re.compile(r'(\d+)\s*(\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)|-\s*(\d+))?')   # this will match the ITEMs in the format \d+|\d+(\d+)|\d+-\d+
    for line in reader:
        s_obj = obj1.search(line)             
        if s_obj:               # If this line contains the input in the desired format, then go ahead and process it, otherwise ignore
            list_index = int(s_obj.group(1))          
            all = obj2.finditer(s_obj.group(2))    # s_obj.group(2) contains the matched items and their quantity such as 56(5) 57(3)| 56 | 67-45 
            index_items = []                      # this will hold all the items for the current index and their quantities
            for m in all:
                item_quantity = [m.group(1), '1']    # if item is not followed by '()' or '-' assume it's 1
                if m.group(2):                     # If it's followed by '()' or '-' update its count with the number following '(' or '-'
                    item_quantity[1] = m.group(3) if not m.group(4) else m.group(4)
                index_items.append(item_quantity)

            index_dict[list_index] = index_items


    sorted_keys = sorted(index_dict.keys())  # sort the keys as dictionary might not give keys in the ascending order and it's assumed that list indices would be in ascending order
    writer.write("{0: >10} {1: >10} {2: >10}\n".format("LIST", "ITEM", "Q"))
    for index in sorted_keys:
        for val in index_dict[index]:
            output_line = "{0: >10} {1: >10} {2: >10}\n".format(str(index), val[0], val[1])
            writer.write(output_line)
```

You can modify formatting to output in the format that suits your needs. Here is the sample input that I used-

```
List  ITEM
1    56(5) 57(1)
2    23
3    21-9
4    9(3) 5(4) 89-9
```

and corresponding output on running the above program-

```
      LIST     ITEM         Q
      1         56          5
      1         57          1
      2         23          1
      3         21          9
      4          9          3
      4          5          4
      4         89          9
```